# To print root url in rails 3 application using helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

OK I have a pretty simple problem which I'm not being able to solve.
I have a link that I'm showing to my users by the following ruby code in a rails 3 application:-

```
<%= link_to linkbunch_url(@link.link), linkbunch_url(@link.link) %>
```

This is printing a url like this:-

```
http://localhost:3000/linkbunches/7yae8t
```

Now I don't want this "linkbunches" to be part of my url. So I changed my routes.rb file and defined a path like:-

```
match "/:id" => "linkbunches#show"
```

So when I'm changing the url from `http://localhost:3000/linkbunches/7yae8t` to `http://localhost:3000/7yae8t` it's taking me to the same page. No problem at all. 
But I don't understand how to actually change the ruby code so that it don't prints the controller name. I tried with `root_url(@link.link)` but it didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly name the route with the `:as` option.

```
match "/:id" => "linkbunches#show", as: :linkbunch
```

Notice how your original route is nameless

```
➜  ~ ✗ rake routes | grep bunch
                /:id(.:format)    linkbunches#show
```

and once you've named it as I showed above

```
➜  ~ ✗ rake routes | grep bunch
   linkbunch    /:id(.:format)    linkbunches#show
```

This will allow you to continue using `linkbunch_url(@link.link)` in your views.

Answer (score 0):

@Deefour is right. One thing I would recommend however is to always limit your HTTP methods as you see fit. So instead of `match`, use `get`:

```
get "/:id" => "linkbunches#show", as: :linkbunch
```

You could use `match` with `via: :get` (this will be required when using `match` in the future Rails versions) but prefer the other explicit form.